# receive when service is down

Tags: android, service

I am building an application where I need a service which will never stop like android system services. I can make my service restarted by system using start_not_sticky but there is no guarantee that my service will never stop. So my idea is if there is any way to broadcase receive when my service will be goes off I can restarted the service. Is there any way to receive that?

Comment: I think u can do some thing on onDestroy()...........

Comment: why don't you run your service foreground? startForeground() is there for you to run critical services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation explains it best :

- Use the `startForeground(int, Notification)` API to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a candidate for killing when low on memory . (It is still theoretically possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure from the current foreground application, but in practice this should not be a concern.)
- Note this means that most of the time your service is running, it may be killed by the system if it is under heavy memory pressure. If this happens, the system will later try to restart the service. An important consequence of this is that if you implement onStartCommand() to schedule work to be done asynchronously or in another thread, then you may want to use `START_FLAG_REDELIVERY` to have the system re-deliver an Intent for you so that it does not get lost if your service is killed while processing it

Comment: actually I use startForeground() method in one of my application but unfortunately it did not works well, still that time my service became stop sometimes by system. then I solved the problem using alarm, triggering an alarm when I need to do some work. You know alarm is costly if you consider battery consumption. thats why I need something better.